# How do I open a Java .jps file?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, profiling

I have been sent a Java .jps file which contains the output of some kind of performance anaysis (from a profiling run, I believe).

I need to take a look at it, ideally through Eclipse (if a suitable plugin exists).

Unfortunately, when I search with Google for "JPS" it spell-checks it to "JSP"  for which there are a huge number of useless hits.

I have the Eclipse Memory Analyser installed, but it doesn't seem to recognise the file.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=jps+file

Comment: This is a JProfiler snapshot: https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html

Comment: Indeed, it is. Thanks for that.